# How to use wp_nav_menu to create a select menu dropdown?

Tags: dropdown, select, menus

I'm using the following inside the [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function to create a select dropdown menu where each menu item is an option in the select dropdown...

```
'items_wrap' => '<select>%3$s</select>'
'before'     => '<option value="">'
'after'      => '</option>'
```

How do I add the link value in the `'before'` declaration? Is there a better way to go about this? I know about [`wp_dropdown_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages), but that doesn't work because I want users to be able to control the menu from the "Menus" page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't do this with wp_nav_menu, because it outputs list items, and you'll generate invalid markup with your code.

Try using [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) instead.

---

A quick solution for a drop down menu with a custom walker:

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

    // don't output children opening tag (`<ul>`)
    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth){}

    // don't output children closing tag    
    public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth){}

    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args){

      // add spacing to the title based on the current depth
      $item->title = str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 4) . $item->title;

      // call the prototype and replace the <li> tag
      // from the generated markup...
      parent::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args);
      $output = str_replace('<li', '<option', $output);
    }

    // replace closing </li> with the closing option tag
    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
      $output .= "</option>\n";
    }
}
```

In your templates use it like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'primary', // your theme location here
  'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown(),
  'items_wrap'     => '<select>%3$s</select>',
));
```

Comment: Actually, when using the "items_wrap" part, that removes the list items, so the markup is ok. I'll check out the link though. Thanks!

Comment: yes, but that doesn't handle the nested `<UL>`s :)

Comment: It actually does :-)

Comment: According to the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L17) it doesn't, unless you're using a custom walker...

Comment: Does this work or not?

Comment: @OneTrickPony - how would you suggest implementing a select button with this method?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by select button? A link with a dropdown menu?

Comment: What I mean is, using this code, the select box shows up, but nothing happens when you select an item. How would you implement a button that sends the user to the selected page/menu item? Screenshot: http://f.cl.ly/items/3T3t250Y04031J2o2L1l/Image%202012-03-06%20at%201.30.03%20PM.png

Comment: either with javascript, using the [onchange](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5150421/376947) event, or wrap it in a form and add a submit button, and handle the redirection yourself during form processing

Comment: Does the walker work?? It doesn't show dropdown box with default theme

Comment: Yes, it does work. Working as of Nov 24, 2012. Cut & paste the "wp_nav_menu(array( ..." part in you theme, where you want the dropdown to appear. DO NOT leave it in functions.php file. If you do, the dropdown will end up appearing when functions.php is called & so it may appear at the top of the actual content, which is undesirable. So simply copy the function to functions.php file & copy wp_nav_menu where you want it to appear, save both files & reload page. That should do it. And I am using WP3+ version, so make sure you update your WP version. It may NOT work on older version.

Comment: I had to replace this "parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);" for this "parent::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args);" to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that useful:

You can follow any responses to simplify css code dropdovn menu.

1. Add a class `parent` for items that have a submenu
2. add `depth` class (depth0 , depth1, depth2 ...)

add to function.php your theme

```
class DD_Wolker_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ){
        $GLOBALS['dd_children'] = ( isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) )? 1:0;
        $GLOBALS['dd_depth'] = (int) $depth;
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_parent_css',10,2);
function  add_parent_css($classes, $item){
     global  $dd_depth, $dd_children;
     $classes[] = 'depth'.$dd_depth;
     if($dd_children)
         $classes[] = 'parent';
    return $classes;
}
```

now in header.php

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => '','container' => '',  'menu' => 'header-menu', 'walker'=> new DD_Wolker_Menu ) );
```

`header-menu` replaced by the name of your menu

CSS example code may be the

```
#menu-header-menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu-header-menu  ul{

}

#menu-header-menu> li{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1.618em;
}
#menu-header-menu  li{
    list-style: none;
}
#menu-header-menu  li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:  1em;
    font-family:    'Lato',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif ;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#menu-header-menu li.parent::after{
    content:'+';
}

#menu-header-menu  .sub-menu {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #fff;
}

#menu-header-menu  li:hover>.sub-menu{
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
    z-index: +1;
}
```

where `#menu-header-menu` - id the main UL list (you need to update that as well)

Answer (score -1):

[Dropdown Menus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menus/) plugin *does* answer the question: `wp_nav_menu` can't be used to create select menu dropdown, whereas plugin provides nifty `dropdown_menu()` function that does the job admirably.