# Wrap wp_nav_menu output around option tags for select menu

Tags: menus

I have set up a wp_nav_menu in Wordpress. I have 2 parent categories, with 2 sub-categories each, so this produces a nested list.

My current code to call this menu is...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
        array( 
            'theme_location'    =>  'shop-categories',
            'container'         =>  'nav',
            'container_class'   =>  'shop-cat'
        ) 
    ); ?>
```

... which outputs this...

(I have simplified the code so you just get an idea of the markup)

```
<nav class="shop-cat">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Clothing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>T-Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a>Tops</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Accessories</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Earings</a></li>
        <li><a>Hats</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I would like to output this...

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Clothing">
    <option value="T-Shirts">T-Shirts</option>
    <option value="Tops">Tops</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Accessories">
    <option value="Earings">Earings</option>
    <option value="Hats">Hats</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

...is this possible to do dynamically? Or will it be better to do this manually? I have had a look around but couldn't find any help on this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: check this [How to use wp_nav_menu to create a select menu dropdown?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27497/how-to-use-wp-nav-menu-to-create-a-select-menu-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function?

It displays or retrieves the HTML dropdown list of categories.
I'm unsure of your exact needs but it could be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. Just display the categories in a Select menu. I will give this a go then report back, it does seem like a good answer